# How to sync files of local filesystem to upload using angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Basically what it means is let's say I upload a file, and then I make some changes to the file, for example, a .txt file. The uploaded file automatically syncs itself with the original file in the local system, we don't have to upload it again. And this will be done either as soon as there is a change or after a fixed interval of time. Is it possible using javascript(angularjs)?

I guess we will need the path of the file that we want to sync and read the file repeatedly after a set interval of time. But browsers are not allowed to access the full path so I am not sure how to proceed with this. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, but I want to clarify that AngularJS is just a framework, so anything possible in regular JavaScript can be built inside/alongside an AngularJS application if it doesn't already exist. So when searching for how to do this, don't worry about the AngularJS constraint. But if this is possible at all, it may be doable through the *experimental* [File System API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem), though I'm just guessing. Basically, start by researching ways for the browser to interact with files *at all* and get more specific from there.

Comment: Also, by "upload a file", you mean to your *browser*, right? As in, the file is then held in the browser tab's memory where it sits until your web app either explicitly sends it to a server (via a POST request or something, for example) or the user closes/navigates away from the page. The *browser's* copy of the file is what you're worried about keeping in sync, right? You're *not* referring to keeping a file in sync between the user's file system and a remote server, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.